# How to select zoomed area by passing range as parameter in plot (High Chart)?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am wokring on zoomin in area of plot in range by passing as parameter. I found very good example for zoom in

```
$(function () {
    // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Chart selection demo'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click and drag the plot area to draw a selection'
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }, {
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4].reverse()
        }]
      });
   });
```

But how can i zoom in area by passing parameter range value (here x-min = 2 and x-max = 6). Pls help me in this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must work with an event and in that event do this:

```
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(2, 6);
```

Comment: i added chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(2, 6); in chart events but no effect. Can u pls update  in http://jsfiddle.net/. Thanks

Comment: Here's an example in fiddle: 

http://jsfiddle.net/dtobzooj/

And I meant events of other components not chart events, but you can also use chart events properly to use this.